# Airflow 1.10.2 not writing logs to S3

Tags: python, amazon-s3, airflow

I'm trying to run airflow in a docker container and send the logs to s3. I've the following environment
Airflow Version: `1.10.2`

Also updated the following in the airflow.cfg

`logging_config_class = log_config.LOGGING_CONFIG`

where `LOGGING_CONFIG` is defined in the class `config/log_config.py`.

I've created following files:

1. `config/__init__.py`
2. `config/log_config.py`

I've set up the `log_config.py` in the following way:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#
# Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
# or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
# distributed with this work for additional information
# regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
# to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
# "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
# with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#   http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
# software distributed under the License is distributed on an
# "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
# KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
# specific language governing permissions and limitations
# under the License.

import os
from typing import Dict, Any

from airflow import configuration as conf
from airflow.utils.file import mkdirs

# TODO: Logging format and level should be configured
# in this file instead of from airflow.cfg. Currently
# there are other log format and level configurations in
# settings.py and cli.py. Please see AIRFLOW-1455.
LOG_LEVEL = conf.get('core', 'LOGGING_LEVEL').upper()


# Flask appbuilder's info level log is very verbose,
# so it's set to 'WARN' by default.
FAB_LOG_LEVEL = conf.get('core', 'FAB_LOGGING_LEVEL').upper()

LOG_FORMAT = conf.get('core', 'LOG_FORMAT')

BASE_LOG_FOLDER = conf.get('core', 'BASE_LOG_FOLDER')

PROCESSOR_LOG_FOLDER = conf.get('scheduler', 'CHILD_PROCESS_LOG_DIRECTORY')

DAG_PROCESSOR_MANAGER_LOG_LOCATION = \
    conf.get('core', 'DAG_PROCESSOR_MANAGER_LOG_LOCATION')

FILENAME_TEMPLATE = conf.get('core', 'LOG_FILENAME_TEMPLATE')

PROCESSOR_FILENAME_TEMPLATE = conf.get('core', 'LOG_PROCESSOR_FILENAME_TEMPLATE')

# Storage bucket url for remote logging
# s3 buckets should start with "s3://"
# gcs buckets should start with "gs://"
# wasb buckets should start with "wasb"
# just to help Airflow select correct handler
REMOTE_BASE_LOG_FOLDER = os.environ['AIRFLOW__CORE__REMOTE_BASE_LOG_FOLDER']

ELASTICSEARCH_HOST = conf.get('elasticsearch', 'ELASTICSEARCH_HOST')

LOG_ID_TEMPLATE = conf.get('elasticsearch', 'ELASTICSEARCH_LOG_ID_TEMPLATE')

END_OF_LOG_MARK = conf.get('elasticsearch', 'ELASTICSEARCH_END_OF_LOG_MARK')

LOGGING_CONFIG = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'airflow': {
            'format': LOG_FORMAT,
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'class': 'airflow.utils.log.logging_mixin.RedirectStdHandler',
            'formatter': 'airflow',
            'stream': 'sys.stdout'
        },
        'task': {
            'class': 'airflow.utils.log.file_task_handler.FileTaskHandler',
            'formatter': 'airflow',
            'base_log_folder': os.path.expanduser(BASE_LOG_FOLDER),
            'filename_template': FILENAME_TEMPLATE,
        },
        'processor': {
            'class': 'airflow.utils.log.file_processor_handler.FileProcessorHandler',
            'formatter': 'airflow',
            'base_log_folder': os.path.expanduser(PROCESSOR_LOG_FOLDER),
            'filename_template': PROCESSOR_FILENAME_TEMPLATE,
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'airflow.processor': {
            'handlers': ['processor'],
            'level': LOG_LEVEL,
            'propagate': False,
        },
        'airflow.task': {
            'handlers': ['task'],
            'level': LOG_LEVEL,
            'propagate': False,
        },
        'flask_appbuilder': {
            'handler': ['console'],
            'level': FAB_LOG_LEVEL,
            'propagate': True,
        }
    },
    'root': {
        'handlers': ['console'],
        'level': LOG_LEVEL,
    }
}  # type: Dict[str, Any]

DEFAULT_DAG_PARSING_LOGGING_CONFIG = {
    'handlers': {
        'processor_manager': {
            'class': 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
            'formatter': 'airflow',
            'filename': DAG_PROCESSOR_MANAGER_LOG_LOCATION,
            'mode': 'a',
            'maxBytes': 104857600,  # 100MB
            'backupCount': 5
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'airflow.processor_manager': {
            'handlers': ['processor_manager'],
            'level': LOG_LEVEL,
            'propagate': False,
        }
    }
}

REMOTE_HANDLERS = {
    's3': {
        'task': {
            'class': 'airflow.utils.log.s3_task_handler.S3TaskHandler',
            'formatter': 'airflow',
            'base_log_folder': os.path.expanduser(BASE_LOG_FOLDER),
            's3_log_folder': REMOTE_BASE_LOG_FOLDER,
            'filename_template': FILENAME_TEMPLATE,
        },
        'processor': {
            'class': 'airflow.utils.log.s3_task_handler.S3TaskHandler',
            'formatter': 'airflow',
            'base_log_folder': os.path.expanduser(PROCESSOR_LOG_FOLDER),
            's3_log_folder': REMOTE_BASE_LOG_FOLDER,
            'filename_template': PROCESSOR_FILENAME_TEMPLATE,
        },
    },
    'gcs': {
        'task': {
            'class': 'airflow.utils.log.gcs_task_handler.GCSTaskHandler',
            'formatter': 'airflow',
            'base_log_folder': os.path.expanduser(BASE_LOG_FOLDER),
            'gcs_log_folder': REMOTE_BASE_LOG_FOLDER,
            'filename_template': FILENAME_TEMPLATE,
        },
        'processor': {
            'class': 'airflow.utils.log.gcs_task_handler.GCSTaskHandler',
            'formatter': 'airflow',
            'base_log_folder': os.path.expanduser(PROCESSOR_LOG_FOLDER),
            'gcs_log_folder': REMOTE_BASE_LOG_FOLDER,
            'filename_template': PROCESSOR_FILENAME_TEMPLATE,
        },
    },
    'wasb': {
        'task': {
            'class': 'airflow.utils.log.wasb_task_handler.WasbTaskHandler',
            'formatter': 'airflow',
            'base_log_folder': os.path.expanduser(BASE_LOG_FOLDER),
            'wasb_log_folder': REMOTE_BASE_LOG_FOLDER,
            'wasb_container': 'airflow-logs',
            'filename_template': FILENAME_TEMPLATE,
            'delete_local_copy': False,
        },
        'processor': {
            'class': 'airflow.utils.log.wasb_task_handler.WasbTaskHandler',
            'formatter': 'airflow',
            'base_log_folder': os.path.expanduser(PROCESSOR_LOG_FOLDER),
            'wasb_log_folder': REMOTE_BASE_LOG_FOLDER,
            'wasb_container': 'airflow-logs',
            'filename_template': PROCESSOR_FILENAME_TEMPLATE,
            'delete_local_copy': False,
        },
    },
    'elasticsearch': {
        'task': {
            'class': 'airflow.utils.log.es_task_handler.ElasticsearchTaskHandler',
            'formatter': 'airflow',
            'base_log_folder': os.path.expanduser(BASE_LOG_FOLDER),
            'log_id_template': LOG_ID_TEMPLATE,
            'filename_template': FILENAME_TEMPLATE,
            'end_of_log_mark': END_OF_LOG_MARK,
            'host': ELASTICSEARCH_HOST,
        },
    },
}

REMOTE_LOGGING = os.environ['AIRFLOW__CORE__REMOTE_LOGGING']

# Only update the handlers and loggers when CONFIG_PROCESSOR_MANAGER_LOGGER is set.
# This is to avoid exceptions when initializing RotatingFileHandler multiple times
# in multiple processes.
if os.environ.get('CONFIG_PROCESSOR_MANAGER_LOGGER') == 'True':
    LOGGING_CONFIG['handlers'] \
        .update(DEFAULT_DAG_PARSING_LOGGING_CONFIG['handlers'])
    LOGGING_CONFIG['loggers'] \
        .update(DEFAULT_DAG_PARSING_LOGGING_CONFIG['loggers'])

    # Manually create log directory for processor_manager handler as RotatingFileHandler
    # will only create file but not the directory.
    processor_manager_handler_config = DEFAULT_DAG_PARSING_LOGGING_CONFIG['handlers'][
        'processor_manager']
    directory = os.path.dirname(processor_manager_handler_config['filename'])
    mkdirs(directory, 0o755)

if REMOTE_LOGGING and REMOTE_BASE_LOG_FOLDER.startswith('s3://'):
    LOGGING_CONFIG['handlers'].update(REMOTE_HANDLERS['s3'])
elif REMOTE_LOGGING and REMOTE_BASE_LOG_FOLDER.startswith('gs://'):
    LOGGING_CONFIG['handlers'].update(REMOTE_HANDLERS['gcs'])
elif REMOTE_LOGGING and REMOTE_BASE_LOG_FOLDER.startswith('wasb'):
    LOGGING_CONFIG['handlers'].update(REMOTE_HANDLERS['wasb'])
elif REMOTE_LOGGING and ELASTICSEARCH_HOST:
    LOGGING_CONFIG['handlers'].update(REMOTE_HANDLERS['elasticsearch'])
```

I've set the required environment variables and read them in the `log_config.py`

```
 1. AIRFLOW__CORE__REMOTE_LOGGING=True
 2. AIRFLOW__CORE__REMOTE_BASE_LOG_FOLDER=s3_bucket_name
 3. AIRFLOW__CORE__REMOTE_LOG_CONN_ID=s3://AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID:AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY@AIRFLOW_LOG_BUCKET_NAME
```

When I start the container, I can see the following log which shows that airflow is reading my custom log config
[image]

But, airflow is not writing any logs to the s3 bucket. I've looked at other similar questions, followed what they have said (as stated in the steps above). Any pointers on what I'm missing.

Following is a snapshot of the airflow web ui DAG run details:

[image]

The logs are created on the container

Comment: Did you run any of your DAGs? I believe it only uploads logs for tasks that are run, not for the core components.

Comment: @Chris I did run the example DAG for testing the same. No logs were written to S3 after a couple successful runs. Updated the question with airflow ui snapshot

Comment: I think the issue was with the format of `AIRFLOW__CORE__REMOTE_BASE_LOG_FOLDER` . It should be `s3://your-bucket-name-here`, where as I was just using bucket name and not pre-prending the `s3`

Comment: I think the issue was with the format of `AIRFLOW__CORE__REMOTE_BASE_LOG_FOLDER` . It should be `s3://your-bucket-name-here`, where as I was just using bucket name and not pre-prending the `s3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue was with the format of AIRFLOW__CORE__REMOTE_BASE_LOG_FOLDER . It should be s3://your-bucket-name-here, where as I was just using bucket name and not pre-prending the s3

Comment: I am doing everything as ur post above, but I am still unable to see any logs on s3.